# race condition while implementing prometheus

Tags: java, prometheus

I'm trying to impelement custom promethues metrics in my application and I suspect there will be a race condition. How can I avoid the race condition.

```
@Component
public class CustomeCounter {

Counter mycounter;

public CustomCounter(CollectorRegistry registry) {
 mycounter = Counter.build().name("test").help("test").register(registry);
}

public void incrementCounter() {
 mycounter.inc();
}
}


@Component
public class Test{

@Resource
private CustomCounter customCounter;

public void testInc() {
customCounter.incrementCounter();
}
}
```

This looks like a potential race condition to me. How can I avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, Prometheus client libraries are thread safe. I don't see such guarantees in the documentation of the java flavor but there are hints [in the README](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java):

- Gauge (and I expect Counter) methods are thread safe

  > Keep in mind that the default inc(), dec() and set() methods on Gauge
  >   take care of thread safety
- Creation of metric (with builder at least) is thread safe

  > The labels() method looks up or creates the corresponding labelled
  >   timeseries. You might also consider storing the labelled timeseries as
  >   an instance variable if it is appropriate. It is thread safe and can
  >   be used multiple times, which can help performance.

Given your code, I don't expect other concurrency issues.